# why am getting this exception: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException

Tags: java, excel, apache

i am reading excel file using apache poi 3.16 here is my code

```
try
        {
            String excelPath = "C:\\Users\\wecme\\Desktop\\AccountStatement.xls";
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));

            // Create Workbook instance holding .xls file   
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

            // Get the first worksheet  
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Iterate through each rows
            java.util.Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                // Get Each Row
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                // Iterating through Each column of Each Row
                java.util.Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    // Checking the cell format
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                   case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                   case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;


                    }  
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }  

        } catch (IOException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
```

my excel data looks like this:

```
Datetime    Description TransactionId   Credit Amount   Debit Amount    Remaining   OdAmount    EnteredBy   Remarks
1/6/2017 8:14   IDEA (9542010237) COMMISSION    GLGHQN  0.31    0   2721.92 0   iNHYD0390437LO  IDEA COMMISSION
```

when i read other file which is not having time with date its reading properly ,but when  i try to read this file this exception coming

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:286)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:758)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:327)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:291)
at excelRead.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:27)
```

please help me , thank you.

Comment: `NotOfficeXmlFileException` - it's expecting an xlsx, not an xls.

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with reading Excel files, but have you tried converting it to the newer .xlsx format? It's just a hunch, so I might be wrong.

Comment: but i have xls and i dont want to re -save  it agin with xlsx, how can i achieve this?

Comment: @Josef Hoppe i have tried with it its coming but i want to read it as it is like .xls

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a `XSSFWorkbook` which is only suitable for working on xlsx files, i.e. the new xml based office format. Your file extension (xls) however suggests that this is the older Microsoft Office (2003 I guess) format. In order to fix the error you need to convert the file to xlsx format or you need to work with a [HSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html)

You can find some samples concerning HSSF here: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html#hssf-only
Some examples concerning XDDF can be found here: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html#xssf-only

Answer (score 0):

According to the code where the Exception is thrown (see: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/ZipPackage.java?view=markup#l286)

And also the name of the package (openxml4j) it is required that the files are in an openxml compatible format. (i.e. xlsx)

In your case the library cannot open the file because it is not in a .zip format that it can open.

This question has also been asked two months ago, maybe this is also helpful:

[How to fix NotOfficeXmlFileException in java Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641081/how-to-fix-notofficexmlfileexception-in-java-apache-poi)

Comment: Well the Q&A you linked to doesn't have any useful answers, so I doubt that it is going to be helpful.

Comment: I thought the aspect that the user on the other question is getting this error still he used a correct xslx file may be of use figuring out what happens here.