# not able to update the excel data - it overwrites the actual data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a code which writes to the excel file using apache poi api. The problem is it everytime writes the new data to the file and not append the data. can you please help me here. Here is my code.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExcelWrite {
    public static void write(AddExcel addExcel){
       try {
           XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("NG.xlsx");
           XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("Scrap Data");



           int lastRow = worksheet.getLastRowNum();
           System.out.println(lastRow);
           Row row = worksheet.createRow(++lastRow);
           row.createCell(2).setCellValue(addExcel.getArtistName());
           row.createCell(3).setCellValue(addExcel.getItemName());
           row.createCell(6).setCellValue(addExcel.getOriginalPrimaryMarket());
           row.createCell(7).setCellValue(addExcel.getAvgResalePrice());
           row.createCell(8).setCellValue(addExcel.getPriceChangedFromPrimaryMarket());
           row.createCell(9).setCellValue(addExcel.getHighestAvgBid());
           row.createCell(10).setCellValue(addExcel.getLastSoldPrice());
           row.createCell(11).setCellValue(addExcel.getSecondayMarketVolume());
           row.createCell(12).setCellValue(addExcel.getSecondarySales());
           row.createCell(13).setCellValue(addExcel.getPrimarySales());
           row.createCell(14).setCellValue(addExcel.getDateCreated());
           row.createCell(16).setCellValue(addExcel.getInstagramURl());
           row.createCell(17).setCellValue(addExcel.getTwitterURL());


           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("NG.xlsx"));
           workbook.write(out);
           out.close();
           System.out.println("Write Successfully.");

       }
       catch(IOException io){
           System.out.println(io.getMessage());
           System.out.println(io.getStackTrace());
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: your file output stream should be in [append](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) mode and even then I don't think the file will be readable if you write it that way. Your best bet is to again read the file using the api and append rows/columns to it rather than appending raw bytes to the file

Comment: Can you please give me the correction in the code, I changed this code to this FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("NG.xlsx"),true);, is there still anything missing?

Comment: NEVER user "new FileOutputStream(new File("NG.xlsx"), true)" beacuse it will ALWAYS brake your code. May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967508/unable-to-open-excel-file-after-excecuting-my-java-apache-poi-program-and-i-am-u/65972752#65972752 read all the answer for hints about how to write new data without overriding existing one. Each time you execute your code, you're RECREATING a new excel DELETING the old one. Another useful link to learn how to update excels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940340/how-to-update-an-excel-file-in-java/65945983#65945983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test (I used 4.1.2 version from maven repository) when you use `createSheet` it produce an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet named 'Scrap Data'
```

With the `getSheet()` method you can grab the existing sheet. If it does not exist you will be get a `null` then you can create a new sheet with the required name.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook;
try {
    File file = new File("NG.xlsx");
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    if(file.exists()) {
       FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
       workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);                
    }
    String sheetName = "Scrap Data";
    XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    if(worksheet == null) {
       worksheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
    }

... //other code unchanged

} catch(Exception io){
  io.printStackTrace();
}
```

NOTE: I changed the file reading code a little bit because I got errors and the documentation says the following:

```
* Note - if the Document was opened from a {@link File} rather
*  than an {@link InputStream}, you <b>must</b> write out to
*  a different file, overwriting via an OutputStream isn't possible.
```

Comment: Getting this error while using your code - org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: using 2016 office, and poi-ooxml 3.15.

Comment: sorry to say but if i downgrage to 3.15 the same code working for me. Possible file corruption? I found a similar problem here: [NotOfficeXmlFileException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641081/how-to-fix-notofficexmlfileexception-in-java-apache-poi) may you can check that. I am tested on windows only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each time you run your code, you always create **a brand new** `XSSFWorkbook` and so **a brand new** excel file, **deleting and overriding** the existing one.

It doesn't matters you're calling `worksheet.getLastRowNum()`; it will **always return -1** because your `XSSFWorkbook` will **always be empty**.

*If you want to update an existing excel file (appending new rows to it), you MUST create your `XSSFWorkbook` by loading that existing excel file.* You're code is broken because with the line

```
  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

you're creating a brand new `XSSFWorkbook` which is *totally unrelated* to the excel file you want to update. You HAVE TO use instead:

```
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(toUpdateExcelFilePath));
```

You might want to have a look at this post for more details: [how to update an existing excel file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940340/how-to-update-an-excel-file-in-java/65945983#65945983).